# Is there an optimal way to render images in cocoa? Im using setNeedsDisplay

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, uiimage, drawing

Currently, any time I manually move a UIImage (via handling the touchesMoved event) the last thing I call in that event is [self setNeedsDisplay], which effectively redraws the entire view.

My images are also being animated, so every time a frame of animation changes, i have to call setNeedsDisplay.

I find this to be horrific since I don't expect iphone/cocoa to be able to perform such frequent screen redraws very quickly.

Is there an optimal, more efficient way that I could be doing this?
Perhaps somehow telling cocoa to update only a particular region of the screen (the rect region of the image)?

Answer (score 3):

setNeedsDisplayInRect: does exactly what you need.

See [documentation at developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setNeedsDisplayInRect:)